# Field in Sequence number 1 is Null Return field in Sequence number 2

Tags: sql, null, db2, isnull, seq

I originally had a placed in the where statement that seq1 (most recent physical address) would be what I want, but if it is LIKE ('SEE%') then give the mailing address.  However, I noticed that in some cases it will say "See Mailing" and then there is a null in the mailing. When that happens I would like to return the Mailing address for sequence 2 instead.  I provided an example of what is happening and what would be desired below.

Sample Data:

```
Cust_ID  SeqNum PhysicalAddress  MailingAddress
1          1        1 Main St     PO Box 1
1          2        1 Main St     PO Box 1
1          3        1 First Ave   PO Box 1
2          1        See Mailing     Null
2          2        See Mailing   2 Main St
2          3        See Mailing   2 Main St
3          1        See Mailing   3 Main St
3          2        3 Main St     3 Main St
3          3        3 Third St    3 Third St
```

Desired Result:

```
Cust_ID  SeqNum      Address
1           1       1 Main St
2           2       2 Main St
3           1       3 Main St
```

Please help me figure out the best way of going about building this query.  Should I build a case in the SELECT clause or combine AND's and OR's in the WHERE clause?

Comment: Do you always want sequence 2 when sequence 1 has "see mailing" and a null mailing address? Or do you want the minimum sequence number for the customer I'd that either has a physical address other than "see mailing" or has "see mailing" and a not null value for mailing address. For example, what would you expect if both sequence 1 and 2 had "see mailing" for physical and null for mailing?

Comment: Maybe edit your question to show the SQL that you currently have, then people might be able to suggest ways of improving it.  Posting DDL, INSERT statements for your test data and what version of Db2 you are using helps too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
SELECT  "Cust_ID"
,       "SeqNum"
,       CASE WHEN "PhysicalAddress" = 'See Mailing' THEN "MailingAddress" ELSE "PhysicalAddress" END AS "Address"
FROM
(
    SELECT T.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY "Cust_Id" ORDER BY "SeqNum") AS "RowNum"
    FROM   "Table" T
    WHERE  "MailingAddress" IS NOT NULL
    OR     "PhysicalAddress" <> 'See Mailing'
)
WHERE "RowNum" = 1
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you for your assistance.. Next time I will also provide the SQL code that I currently have.

Answer (score 0):

Other method (dont remove ID if only one row with null adress)

```
select * from (
    select f1.*,  
    rownumber() over(partition by f1.Cust_ID 
    order by case when (case when f1.PhysicalAddress='See Mailing' then f1.MailingAddress else f1.PhysicalAddress end) is null then cast(null as integer) else SeqNum  end)  rang 
    from FormatedAdresse f1
) tmp where rang=1
```